# Implementation of resize handles in mac OS X using cocoa and objective-c

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Does anyone have any suggests of how to implement resize handles for drawn shapes in Quartz on mac? For example, I have included something similar which can be drawn in PowerPoint:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL5bY.jpg]

I'd like to grant the user power to resize the shapes simply by the usual method of clicking the handles and manipulating them.

Answer (score 1):

For an example of how to implement resizable shape views, check out [SKTGraphicView.m](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Sketch/Listings/SKTGraphicView_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011772-SKTGraphicView_m-DontLinkElementID_14) in Apple’s [Sketch](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/Sketch/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code:
[image]

Sketch is also useful as an example of AppKit’s document architecture and the Model-View-Controller design pattern.